# Cannot see valid timestamp in PDF with Adobe Acrobat XI

Tags: pdf, pdf-generation, itext, trusted-timestamp

I'm trying to verify a timestamp in a LTV PDF document with iText from SVN and Acrobar Reader, my code is boiler plate from iText in action 2ed. iText is happy to verify it but Acrobar Reader says the timestamp is not valid. The timeStamp service uses a SHA256 digest algorithm, i see a couple of things i haven't seen in other timestamp services; the extend usage of the certificate shows more usages than timestamping and both the CRL url and OSCP url are broken, can it be that the cause of the error? I put a link to the PDF below

Much appreciated,

[bad_timestamp.pdf](https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B2A8sgVp_HZbYzNoM1NTM2xwblE/edit?usp=sharing)

Comment: A time stamp successfully verified by iText indicates that the hash values are correct. Thus, Adobe Reader is unhappy about some other detail. Unfortunately it does not tell which. I would guess it is because the extended key usage is not marked critical while RFC 3161 explicitly requires it to be.

Comment: You nailed it, but do you know if that's the reason Adobe shows that the document is modified or tampered with? Thanks!

Comment: Unfortunately Adobe seems to use that message for any issue occurring while verifying the issue with the exception of certificate trust or validity issues.

Comment: And I don't know what exactly is the reason. But I remember another case with missing critical flag.